# Authentication helper function returning undefined instead of boolean

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, axios

I am creating a webpage with client and server using React and Node.

In my client side, in every component, for sensitive pages for certain authorization roles, I have a function to check whether user is logged in and if they are, the component renders as usual.

```
// This section of code is present in all sensitive pages.
const [permit, setPermit] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/checkCookie').then((res) => {
            const result = res.data.authenticated
            if (result) {
                setPermit(true) // conditional rendering of 'permit'
                
            }
})
    }, [])
```

Since I have many components, I created a separate js file and placed this block of code into it, then exported it as a function.

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
export const authService = (cookie) => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/checkCookie", cookie).then(res => {
        if (res.data.authenticated) {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    })

}
```

```
import {authService} from '../api/api'
const [permit, setPermit] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
   setPermit(authService(document.cookie))
}, [])
```

However, the authService helper function does not return true or false. When I console.log(authService(document.cookie)), it returns an undefined value. Within the helper function itself, the code works but when returning a boolean or any value to another component, it simply returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are using async function that does not return anything in your sync code. Hence the undefined. Even if you added `return` in front of `axios.post...`, by simply calling it inside `setPermit(authService(...))`, you will have set `permit` to `promise`, and not the result of that promise. Since that is asynchronous code inside your synchronous code. So you need to wait for result before setting it.

First you should make sure to return `promise` call.

```
 export const authService = (cookie) => {
     return axios.post("http://localhost:3000/checkCookie", cookie).then(res => {
        if (res.data.authenticated) {
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    })
}
```

And in your `useEffect` you should await for that result

```
import {authService} from '../api/api'
const [permit, setPermit] = useState(null)
useEffect(async () => {
   const authenticated = await authService(document.cookie)
   setPermit(authenticated)
}, [])
```